# Draw sting without spritebatch in Monogame/XNA

Tags: xna, textures, rendering, monogame, spritefont

In my project, I would like my text to be scalable without creating artifacts. This is not the case when using the spritebatch scaling settings; it looks pretty ugly.

Is there a way to convert the text to a texture for better scaling, or is there some other alternative? Will I need to pass the texture to an effect, or will that not give the desired results?

Comment: Is this a question about decaling, or a question about infinitely-zoomable text? Or both?

Comment: Lets say its both. And lets also say that I want to do a button in the 3d world so when the player looks at it from a distance the text looks smaller an when he zooms into the button the text looks bigger and scales as a texture would do

Comment: I saw your answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754447/how-to-change-fontsize-during-the-game-in-xna. It's exactly as you said. So I thought about putting my text-texture into an effect.

Comment: For decaled text, I'd suggest Valve's [Improved Alpha-Tested Magnification](http://www.valvesoftware.com/publications/2007/SIGGRAPH2007_AlphaTestedMagnification.pdf) technique.

Comment: A simple fix could also be to simple increase the font size of the spritefont. Of course, it will still become blurry when scaled even bigger, but it will be a lot simpler to implement than a different scaling algorithm.